# Random NSTimer Inverval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

So to initiate an `NSTimer` we do this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.35 target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But what if I want this to run every 0.3 - 0.7 seconds (randomly). I can't do `arc4random` because then it would choose a number and stick to it.

The only way I've thought of is invalidating it every time it run the '`timerMethod`' and then setting a new random time for it but I'm concerned that that will have an effect on the performance.

Is there another way, better to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a timer, use a series of `[self performSelector:@selector(timerMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:<random value>]` calls. It'll look roughly like tail recursion — `timerMethod` will routinely schedule a future call to itself somewhere within it.

Also be mindful of retain cycles. Both `NSTimer` and `performSelector:...` retain their targets. You could either decline to use either and instead use `dispatch_after` having captured only a weak reference, or use an approximate two-stage deallocation where a non-dealloc call explicitly `invalidate`s the timer or sets a flag to tell you not to schedule another call to `timerMethod`.

The GCD solution would look like:

```
- (void)timerMethod
{
    // schedule the next call to timerMethod, keeping only a weak
    // reference to self so as not to extend the lifecycle
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                                   (int64_t)(<random value> * NSEC_PER_SEC));

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        [weakSelf timerMethod];
    });

    // ... and do whatever else here ...
}
```

Comment: THere's no reason (I believe) to bother with the weak reference. There isn't a retain cycle created by the block.

Comment: @rmaddy I disagree. Suppose there were no weak reference. If I've called `timerMethod` at least once, how is `self` ever going to be deallocated?

Comment: The block will release `self` after the block completes.

Comment: I agree with @Tommy, here is different from normal case, `timerMethod` is called circularly.

Comment: FYI - I just created a simple test app that uses the code in this answer (but without the weak reference). I had the `timerMethod` run 5 times and stop. I then dismissed the view controller and the `dealloc` method was called. There is no need for the weak reference.

Comment: @rmaddy the block will release `self` when it completes. Meanwhile, `self` will have been retained by the new block created by the new call to `timerMethod`. If you add a mechanism to prevent a sixth call to `timerMethod` then obviously the situation is different.

Comment: @Tommy But each call to `timerMethod` returns quickly, certainly faster than it is being called. So each method call creates a block and retains `self`. After the `popTime`, the block calls the method. The method returns quickly and the block end. `self` is released. There is no reference cycle. Obviously there needs to be a way to eventually stop the loop when this view controller needs to be dismissed. But other than that, there is no issue and no need for the weak reference.

Comment: @rmaddy calls to `timerMethod` occur serially regardless of execution time since they all occur on the main queue. Returning quickly is nothing to do with it. But, with no `weak`, each call creates a new owning reference by virtue of the block. Each call is also made with an owning reference. There is therefore no moment when `self` can be deallocated. Or you tell us: on which line of the code given will `self`'s retain count be able to hit 0?

Comment: `self` is retained when the block is created. It is released when the block completes which is after it's call to `timerMethod` completes. There is never more than one active block at a time (assuming the `popTime` is longer than the time it takes to run the `timerMethod`). As I said in my last reply, as long as there is some event that allows `timerMethod` to return before kicking off one more block, `self` won't have any further references from any block on the `timerMethod`. Try it. It took me 5 minutes to write a test app proving what I'm saying.

Comment: Well that's the nub of it: simalone and I are talking about the code as posted, you're talking about the code if modified to break the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid the convenience method and use the NSTimer init method, you get a chance to setTolerance

Another alternative is to create a makeTimer method. In it invalidate the timer if it is not nil. Create a new timer using the init method and set a random interval. 
Use the makeTimer method to make your timer.

Comment: `setTolerance:` is about allowing the system to increase CPU sleep time by letting it call multiple timers when it wakes up if it's at close enough to the correct time (as waking up and sleeping aren't free); it's not meant to give you randomness.

Comment: True, but it is unpredictable how much coalescing can and will occur in the OS so this could be used to provide some randomness. Nobody said anything about distribution. It's a dynamic process.